# How do I configure OTR on Openfire?

Tags: security, cryptography, xmpp, openfire, off-the-record-messaging

I'm developing an XMPP client and I want to use Openfire as server. I wanna use the OTR protocol.

How I do to configure this protocol on Openfire server? 
How I do to only permits connections with this protocol?

I have searched in other questions and I have read the documentation about Content Filter plugin but I can't find how to configure it.

I think that could be a good idea that test this functionality on my server with a full client that uses this protocol, like Pidgin or Chatsecure.

Anyone can help me with this configuration?

Thanks!!

Comment: OTR as a protocol is entirely client-side; no server support is required.

Comment: OK! But this means that I don't have to configure anything? 

Can I restrict the connections only for my this protocol? 

Can I restrict the connections only for my client?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, were you able to enable OTR in openfire?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing related to Server, You have to build it on client.
You may start exploring how it works on some Open Source Apps like [ChatSecure](https://chatsecure.org/) . I recommend you to download the source and look at it.

Comment: but the server has to be configured to receive OTR message

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal correct me if wrong, OTR is off the record message, means no copy of original message will be retained by the server once delivered, and the actual message body will be encrypted end to end.

OpenFire work is to get message from A and push to B, no matter weather the message body is plain text or encrypted. whole encryption thing is done by the clients. unless and until you wanted to even delete the logs of any message sent.

Comment: I think you're correct. OTR is client side. Have you done any complete implementation of OTR in any android app?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal never completely implemented the OTR, just used once as a small hobby project. I was using **CHATSECURE** (a 3rd party open source client)